# Library Migration

Tags: linux, libraries

I have one pre-compiled shared library, which require GLIBC-2.9 But I want to use it against GLIBC-2.8.

I am very much sure, source code have not used any function which was introduces in 2.9

Since the library is closed-source, I can not download source code and compiled it against the desired environment.

Is there any method to use pre-compiled library in another environment ?

Comment: Keep in mind that compiling code with some library means using this library ABI. And function names are not the only thing that's part of the ABI. If, for example, some datatype struct was changed between versions, you code won't work. So it's not enough to be sure that the code have not used any function introduced in new version.

Answer (score 2):

You could bundle that 3rd party library with a copy of glibc-2.9 or newer. Nnote that you'll probably have to include more than `libc.so.6`, like `libpthread` and any other libc component that the library or your application may require and the dynamic linker itself, and call the application like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/where/those/are /path/to/newer/ld.so your-application`.

Alternatively, you could use a `chroot` where that newer libc is installed (and everything needed by your application)